# Django - How define field name for reverse related model in select_related

Tags: python, django

So, i have this models:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    descr = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    external_id = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64,db_index=True)

class Programm(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    descr = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    is_live = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)

class Guide(models.Model):
    programm = models.ForeignKey(Programm)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    descr = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(db_index=True)
    duration = models.TimeField(blank=True)
```

When i need build list of tv shows for one channel:

```
Guide.objects.select_related().filter(programm__channel=channel,
    start_date__lte=timezone.now().date()+timezone.timedelta(days=7),
    start_date__gte=timezone.now().date()-timezone.timedelta(days=1))
```

Django performs such query:

```
SELECT `tvguide_guide`.`id`, 
       `tvguide_guide`.`programm_id`, 
        /*here all fields from all tables */ 
FROM `tvguide_guide` 
     INNER JOIN `tvguide_programm` ON 
     (`tvguide_guide`.`programm_id` = `tvguide_programm`.`id`) 
     INNER JOIN `tvguide_channel` ON 
     (`tvguide_programm`.`channel_id` = `tvguide_channel`.`id`) 
WHERE (`tvguide_programm`.`channel_id` = 1 AND 
       `tvguide_guide`.`start_date` >= '2014-01-16' AND 
       `tvguide_guide`.`start_date` <= '2014-01-24' )
ORDER BY `tvguide_guide`.`start_date` ASC, `tvguide_guide`.`start_time` ASC
```

Django documentation says:

> You can also refer to the reverse direction of a OneToOneField in the
>   list of fields passed to select_related — that is, you can traverse a
>   OneToOneField back to the object on which the field is defined.
>   Instead of specifying the field name, use the related_name for the
>   field on the related object.

So... How it should look??? I can not figure out =( Set an example, please.
In the end, I have a SQL query that would look like this:

```
 SELECT `tvguide_guide`.`name`, 
        `tvguide_guide`.`descr`, 
        `tvguide_guide`.`start_date`, 
        `tvguide_guide`.`start_time`, 
        `tvguide_programm`.`name`,
        `tvguide_channel`.`name` FROM ...
```

Comment: I tried to do so: select_related('name','descr','start_date','start_time','programm__name','programm__channel__name') but it does not work.

Comment: You don't have any OneToOneFields in your models, so I'm confused about what you are actually asking.

Comment: yes, this is my bad =(... and yet, how to tell Django to request only those fields that are required, but not everything?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special for that. Just refer to the class variables directly:

```
guides = Guide.objects.select_related("programm", "programm__channel").filter(programm__channel=channel,
    start_date__lte=timezone.now().date()+timezone.timedelta(days=7),
    start_date__gte=timezone.now().date()-timezone.timedelta(days=1))
programms = [guide.programm for guide in guides]
channels = [programm.channel for programm in programms]
```

Notice that `select_related` is modified to cache the values in the query.